# ImageCropper use with Uint8List file -flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I'm using `image_picker` & `ImageCropper` packages. I want to save a user-given picture in firestore database. So, I use functions like this.

- First, set `File? _image;`
- Functions for cropping & picking

  ```
  Future _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
           Navigator.of(context).pop();
          try {
            final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
             if (image == null) return;
             File? img = File(image.path);
      img = await _cropImage(imageFile: img);
      setState(() {
        _image = img;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }

        Future<File?> _cropImage({required File imageFile}) async {
    CroppedFile? croppedImage =
        await ImageCropper().cropImage(sourcePath: imageFile.path);
    if (CroppedFile == null) return null;
    return File(croppedImage!.path);
  }
  ```

and use this to save data in firestore

```
Future<String> uploadImageToStorage(
    File file,
  ) async {
    file
    Reference ref =
        _storage.ref().child("profilePics").child(_auth.currentUser!.uid);

    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(file);

    TaskSnapshot snap = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }
```

Above function not work for File type data, It support for Uint8List. So, What can I do for this?

Next problem is, I'm getting File type data with ImagePicker for profile picture. Is it not problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `_cropImage`-Method to return `XFile?` like this:

```
Future<XFile?> _cropImage({required File imageFile}) async {
  CroppedFile? croppedImage =
      await ImageCropper().cropImage(sourcePath: imageFile.path);
  if (CroppedFile == null) return null;
  return XFile(croppedImage!.path);
}
```

You also have to change the paramter of `uploadImageToStorage` to `XFile file`. Then you can use `file!.readAsBytes();` to get a `Uint8List`.

```
Future<String> uploadImageToStorage(
  XFile file,
) async {
  Reference ref =
      _storage.ref().child("profilePics").child(_auth.currentUser!.uid);

  final fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();
  UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(fileBytes);

  TaskSnapshot snap = await uploadTask;
  String downloadUrl = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
  return downloadUrl;
}
```

Comment: It says The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'. (store function)

Comment: I updated the answer. I forgot you need to `await` the method first since it is a `Future`.

Comment: Done. Now, going to check it, before it - I display the image on CircleAvatar. When I use File type, I set it like this backgroundImage : FileImage(image). When I change the type file to Xfile. How to set it as background?

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. If you hv time, please answer above q.

Comment: You can convert it back to `File` using the same strategy. `File file = File(xFile.path);`